# Same pickups, Different guitar

Tags: electric-guitar

I'd like to get a Gibson Les Paul and use it for a heavy sound. The price tag however is a little too high for me. It got me thinking though, what if I just bought a less expensive guitar with the same pickup configuration. Which then lead me to think, what would happen if you used the same set of pickups in a different guitar. What would determine the sound in both guitars when compared to each other.

Answer (score 3):

It gets close, but not too close. The exact placing may not be the same, the circuitry also, and certainly the wood will make a difference. As will the bridge. I thought like you, and put a tele pup on a different guitar. It sounds something like, but will never give the same twang as it did on a pukka tele - sadly.